# Why is Super User asking me to sign up? This does not happen for other Stack Exchange sites

Tags: support, login, unregistered-users

I can see [my account](https://superuser.com/users/705504/a-sid) and my Q&A history for Super User, but when I try to ask a new question, I am asked to sign up:

[image]

I don't see this issue with any other Stack Exchange site. What is going on?

Comment: @rene Not a duplicate of that question. This appears to be a different problem, based on the screenshot: the top bar shows them signed in and the button is the same one that shows for *unregistered* accounts. It's not a cross-domain cookie issue, but that somehow their account is recognized as unregistered.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I asked a question on SuperUser as an unregistered user. During the process, I was asked to provide my email ID and I did.

Comment: Ah, then it seems that the issue is that you've accidentally created a second unregistered account on Super User instead of using your overall profile. See [How can one link / merge / combine / associate two accounts / users? (Anonymous / unregistered / cookie, or Google / Facebook / registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous) for how to join it to your main account.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog When I put the link for my [unregistered account](https://superuser.com/users/1801482/user1801482), SE does not go through and keeps telling me to provide the missing URL. Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This happens to me on Chess stack exchange

Comment: @a_sid no bug. You should not mix accounts in the same browser. You can either use different browser, or create a new profile if the browser supports it. (Chrome does, don't know about others)

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard I am confused. Doesn't this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/contact/submit) let you merge two accounts, irrespective of any other factors?

Comment: @a_sid yes, it does. How is it relevant to what I said? If you'll keep using same browser profile for more than one account, same issue will happen again, and SE team will stop helping you if you'll flood them.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog not a duplicate, but it may help.

Comment: I emailed the SE team and they fulfilled my request. Now I can access my SuperUser account just like all my other SE accounts